# Problem calling variables in a function. UnboundLocalError: local variable 'prev_avg_gain' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, local, unbound

I am trying to write a function to calculate RSI data using input from a list or by pulling live price data from an API.

The script worked fine when feeding it data directly from a list, but while I am trying to convert it to a function, I am experiencing issues.

The function needs to remember the output from a previous run in order to calculate a smoothed average, but I keep getting an error that the local variable is being called before assignment.  I've eliminated a lot of the code to keep the post short, but it errors on the 15th run. On the 14th run I think I am defining the variable and printing the value, so I don't understand why it errors.

```
def calc_rsi(price, i):
     while price != complete:
        window.append(price)

        if i == 14:
            avg_gain = sum(gains) / len(gains)
            avg_loss = sum(losses) / len(losses)
           

        if i > 14:
            avg_gain = (prev_avg_gain * (window_length - 1) + gain) / window_length
            avg_loss = (prev_avg_loss * (window_length - 1) + loss) / window_length


        if i >= 14:
            rs = avg_gain / avg_loss
            rsi = round(100 - (100 / (1 + rs)), 2)
            prev_avg_gain = avg_gain
            prev_avg_loss = avg_loss
            print ("rsi", rsi)
            print ("gain", prev_avg_gain)
            print ()
```

The thing that is throwing me for a real loop (pun intended) is that on run 14, my print statement 'print ("gain=", prev_avg_gain)' returns the proper value, so I know that it is assigning a value to the variable....  I've tried adding the 'prev_avg_gain = avg_gain ' to the block of code for 'if i == 14:' and 'if i > 14:' rather than doing it once in the >= block and it throws the same error.

I am new to python and scripting so please go easy :)

Comment: The basic problem is that `prev_avg_gain` isn't defined. Since you don't access it until `i > 14` (i.e., it's 15) it doesn't error until the 15th run.

Comment: @philosofool I am defining it in the if 'i >= 14' block and the print statement there returns the expected value....  I tried defining it as 0 outside of the function and experienced the same error

I also tried moving the prev_avg_gain = avg_gain into the i == 14 block and get the same error....

Comment: Yeah, but shortly before you define it, you call it in the block with `if i > 14`. So, it fails.

Comment: To understand why this also creates an error when you define the variable outside the function, you should know that Python creates the variable name space for a function when the function is created at run time, then read up on `UnboundLocalError`.

Comment: @philosofool but I am defining it on run 14 and calling it on run 15...  I don't understand why it would fail...  

but if that really is the problem, how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I got some help on a different forum and I still don't understand exactly why, but I guess python resets the 'prev_avg_gain' variable every time it looped so to fix this I created a dictionary outside of the function and updated the dictionary with the variable data when required.

```
prev_avg = {}
# Calculate Price Differences
def calc_rsi(price, i):
    
    while price != "complete":
        window.append(price)
        # print (i)
        
        
    # Calculate Average Gains and Losses
            if i == 14:
                avg_gain = sum(gains) / len(gains)
                avg_loss = sum(losses) / len(losses)
               

            if i > 14:
                avg_gain = (prev_avg["prev_avg_gain"] * (window_length - 1) + gain) / window_length
                avg_loss = (prev_avg["prev_avg_loss"] * (window_length - 1) + loss) / window_length
                # prev_avg_gain = avg_gain
                # prev_avg_loss = avg_loss
                # print (output)

            if i >= 14:
                rs = avg_gain / avg_loss
                rsi = round(100 - (100 / (1 + rs)), 2)
                
                prev_avg["prev_avg_gain"] = avg_gain
                prev_avg["prev_avg_loss"] = avg_loss
                # print ("rsi", rsi)
                # print ("gain", prev_avg["prev_avg_gain"])
                # print ()
```

Answer (score 0):

The code as you have pasted will work, if you make **one** call to `calc_rsi()` where `i` is incremented from `<=14` to `>14`. In this case `prev_avg_gain` will be *remembered*. But if you make 2 calls to `calc_rsi()` then `prev_avg_gain` will **not be remembered** between calls.

To demonstrate, I use a trimmed down example:

```py
def calc_rsi(price, i):
     while i <= price:
        if i == 14:
            avg_gain = 10

        if i > 14:
            avg_gain = (prev_avg_gain * (10 - 1) + 1) / 5

        if i >= 14:
            prev_avg_gain = avg_gain
            print ("gain", prev_avg_gain)

        i += 1

# i loops from 13 to 16 in one call, this works!
calc_rsi(price=16, i=14)

# i loops from 13 to 14, prev_avg_gain is set
calc_rsi(price=14, i=13)
# i loops from 15 to 16, throws error! because prev_avg_gain is not remembered
calc_rsi(price=16, i=15)
```